# A map on the unit ball

Tags: geometry, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $B$ be the unit ball of $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$, i.e. $B=\lbrace x\in \ell^2(\mathbb{N}): \|x\|\le 1\rbrace.$ For each $x=(x_1,x_2,\cdots)\in B$, let 
$$f(x)=(1-\|x\|,x_1,x_2,\cdots).$$ Define $T:B\to 2^B$ by $$T(x)=B(f(x),r(x))\cap B, \mbox{ where }r(x)=\frac{1}{2}(\|x-f(x)\|).$$
Is it true that $$D(Tx,Ty)\le \|x-y\| \mbox{ for all }x,y\in B?$$
Here $B(y,r)$ denotes the closed ball with radius $r$ centered at $y$, and $D$ is the Hausdorff metric defined by $$D(A,B)=\inf\lbrace r>0: N_r(A)\supset B, 
N_r(B)\supset A\rbrace,$$ $N_r(S) =\lbrace x\in C: d(x,S)\lt r\rbrace$ being the 
$r$-neighborhood of $S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's wrong: Take $x=0$ and $y=e_1=(1,0,0,\dots)$. Then $f(x)=e_1$ and $f(y)=e_2=(0,1,0,\dots)$, so $r(x) = 1/2$ and $r(y) = \sqrt2/2$. Now it is not hard to see that $p = (-\sqrt7/4,3/4,0,\dots)$ is the point in $Ty = B(f(y),r(y))\cap B$ farthest away from $f(x)$. From this one deduces that
$$
  D(Tx,Ty) = \sqrt{(1+\sqrt7/4)^2+(3/4)^2} - 1/2 = \sqrt{2+\sqrt7/2} - 1/2  > 1 = \|x-y\|.
$$
(As $Ty$ is the larger chunk, geometric considerations show that $Ty \subseteq N_r(Tx)$ implies $Tx \subseteq N_r(Ty)$, for all $r>0$.)

Comment: Let $p=(-\sqrt{7}/4, 3/4,0,0,\cdots)\in T(y)$. According to my calculation the minimum distance $d(p, Tx)$ from $p$ to $Tx$ is  $$\sqrt{(1+\sqrt{7}/4)^2+9/16}-1/2\approx 1.32287…$$
So $D(Tx, Ty)\ge 1.32287>\|x-y\|$ (but I am not able to show   $D(Tx, Ty)\ge\|f(x)-f(y)\|$). This is enough to show that $T$ is not nonexpansive.  Thus my previous question [Multi-valued Nonexpansive Maps][1] is still open.

[1]:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12444/multi-valued-nonexpansive-maps

Comment: @TCL: I'm not exactly sure what you're doing with the $p$. Have a close look at your definition of $D(A,B)$: It's not the minimum distance of $A$ and $B$ but the Hausdorff distance. There you've got $D(B(x,s),B(y,r))=\|x−y\|+|r−s|≥\|x−y\|$.

Comment: Don't forget that the definition of $T$ includes an intersection with B(0,1).

Comment: @TCL: You're quite right, sorry; thanks for pointing that out. As you see from my corrected answer, now I do understand what you're doing with the $p$ `:-)`.